Is mask 255.255.255.127 used anywhere?
I am still learning and I've found that there is a formula to calculate: 2*n - 2(where n is number of zeros  i.e. digits of hosts).
I am trying to calculate for mask: 255.255.255.127
I've converted it to binary I've got
11111111.11111111.11111111.11111110
Here we've got only one zero. So by formula it gives 2*1 - 2 = 0 So it means cannot have any hosts except network address and broadcast address?.
Is it correct?
If it's correct why it's like that and is it used anywhere?

See RFC 3021. If you mean /31, that is widely used for P2P links as a replacement for a wasteful /30 subnet.

That's not a valid netmask. 127 == 0111 1111 You have your zero on the wrong end. 254 is the mask you're talking about. (i.e /31)

@Either the OP didn't get their bits together correctly or .254 was intended. Discontiguous netmasks aren't supported nowadays, that is correct.
